# How to enable the SUN security provider on IBM JDK J9 (java 1.6.0) built for WebSphere 8.5?

Tags: java, cryptography, sun

I have a java program which runs perfectly well on SUN JRE 1.6. However, when I ran it on `IBM JDK J9 built for WebSphere 8.5`, it threw following exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchProviderException: Provider SUN is not available
```

I wrote a java program to list all available providers on IBM JDK J9 and found the SUN provider was missing, even though I have already included following line in the java.security file under.

`$JAVA_HOME/lib/security (i.e. /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/security)` :

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

What else am I missing? Could someone please tell me how to enable / install this "SUN provider" on IBM JDK J9? Thank you so much!

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the Sun provider is only available on the Sun JRE. Insisting on a single provider is a bug in the application you're trying to run. Can you fix it or can you complain to the vendor?

Comment: @ntoskrnl I don't think the Sun provider is only available on the Sun JRE. I checked the IBM J9 (java 1.7) from IBM's eclipseDevelopmentPackage and it also supports Sun provider.

Comment: Provide a link that shows the Sun provider is supported.

Comment: @GregS Right you are. According what I found, there is just the "IBMJCE" provider for cryptographic primitives by default: "The IBM JCE provider replaces the Sun providers sun.security.provider.Sun, com.sun.rsajca.Provider, and com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE."